# Magento 2 Restrict SKU Characters

Tags: admin, product-attribute, magento2.2.2, sku, sku-length

I am using Magento 2.2.2.

I want to restrict the number of SKU characters to be entered in the Admin Product Detail Page. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update you eav_attribute table

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET frontend_class = "validate-length maximum-length-11" where attribute_code = 'sku'
```

Comment: how to fix this from code level so whenever we edit the product it will not raised the error "Please enter less or equal than 64 symbols."

Comment: Nice answer mohan.